# Extract data from a pdf into a table

Tags: python, r, pdf, pdf-extraction

[pdf example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhV6L.png)

[image: family names]

I want to extract species information from a large pdf file (example in the image) into a list with each species as a row and the metadata as columns. Is there a way to do this in python or R?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to simply use the `pdftool` library.

There are two parts of my solution:

1. Put 1 paragraph (species) into one row of a data.frame
2. Separate the information of the text into meta.data columns

*Part 1: Set 1 species information per row of a data.frame:*

```
# get the path of the pdf:
file_name <- "species_info.pdf"
# read the text in the pdf:
species.raw.text <- pdf_text(pdf = file_name, opw = "", upw = "")
# split the text into part. Each corresponding to 1 species
species.raw.text <- str_split(species.raw.text, "\n\n")
# convert the list into a data.frame i.e. each row = 1 species
species.df <- as.data.frame(species.raw.text)
# change the column name to raw.text
colnames(species.df) <- c("raw.text")
```

*Part 2: Extract the information from the raw text into columns:*

For this I used the `dplyr` library with the `separate()` function. I supposed that each species has the same type of information i.e.

- species name
- Gulf of Suez:
- Gulf of Aqaba:
- Red Sea main basin:
- General distribution:
- Remark:

I suggest this code to get what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
# remove the `\n`
species.df$raw.text <- gsub("\n", " ", species.df$raw.text)
# get the meta.data
species.df <- species.df %>% 
  separate(
    col = raw.text, sep = "Gulf of Suez:", 
    into = c("species.name", "rest")) %>%
  separate(
    col = rest, sep = "Gulf of Aqaba:", 
    into = c("Gulf.of.Suez", "rest")) %>%
  separate(
    col = rest, sep = "Red Sea main basin:", 
    into = c("Gulf.of.Aqaba", "rest")) %>%
  separate(
    col = rest, sep = "General distribution:", 
    into = c("Red.Sea.main.basin", "rest")) %>%
  separate(
    col = rest, sep = "Remark:", fill = "right",
    into = c("General.distribution", "Remark"))
```

| species.name | Gulf.of.Suez | Gulf.of.Aqaba | Red.Sea.main.basin | General.distribution | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carcharhinus albimarginatus (Rüppell 1837) | - | Israel (Baranes 2013). | Egypt (Rüppell 1837, as Carcharias albimarginatus), Sudan (Ninni 1931), Saudi Arabia (Spaet & Berumen 2015). | Red Sea, Indo-Pacific: East Africa east to Panama. | NA |
| Carcharhinus altimus (Springer 1950) | - | Egypt (Baranes & Ben-Tuvia 1978a), Israel (Baranes & Golani 1993). | Saudi Arabia (Spaet & Berumen 2015). | Circumglobal in tropical and warm temperate seas. | NA |
| Carcharhinus amboinensis (Müller & Henle 1839) | - | - | Saudi Arabia (Spaet & Berumen 2015). | Circumglobal in tropical and warm temperate seas, but not eastern Pacific. | NA |
| Carcharhinus brevipinna (Müller & Henle 1839) | Egypt (Gohar & Mazhar 1964, as Aprionodon brevipinna). | - | Egypt (Gohar & Mazhar 1964, as Aprionodon brevipinna and Carcharhinus maculipinnis), Saudi Arabia (Spaet & Berumen 2015). | Circumglobal in tropical and warm temperate seas, but not in the eastern Pacific. | Not a Lessepsian migrant as previously reported by Ben-Tuvia (1966) (see Golani et al. 2002). |
| Carcharhinus falciformis (Müller & Henle 1839) | - | - | Egypt (Gohar & Mazhar 1964, as Carcharhinus menisorrah), Saudi Arabia (Klausewitz 1959a, as Carcharhinus menisorrah; Spaet & Berumen 2015). | Circumglobal in tropical seas. | NA |

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful, the document is organized by family names (in all caps - I added another picture to the orginal post) do you have an idea how to deal with this?